# Bootstrap selectpicker + mCustomScrollbar not working as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, custom-scrolling

I am trying to achieve custom scroll bar on bootstrap select picker. But it was not working as expected.
Please find the fiddle here

```
$(objElm).selectpicker({
      size: 4
});

$('.dropdown-menu.inner, objElm').mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"dark"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/20a66247/2/

your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap style override and set timeout helped me to achieve what I expected. PFB the updated fiddle

`$('.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker').on('click', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var jDropdown = $('.dropdown-menu.open ');
        if(!jDropdown.hasClass("mCustomScrollbar")) {
            jDropdown.mCustomScrollbar({
                axis:"y", 
                autoDraggerLength:false, 
                dropupAuto: false,
                advanced: {
                    updateOnBrowserResize: true,
                    updateOnContentResize: false,
                    autoScrollOnFocus: false
                }
            });
        }
    }, 50);
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/20a66247/6/